# Action Item not clickable in Android ActionBar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBar with this item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    [...]
    <item android:id="@+id/status_service"
        android:icon="@drawable/network_service"
        android:title="@string/status_service"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText|collapseActionView"/>
</menu>
```

But I don't want it to be a button. Is a way to set it as non clickable. The layout and appearance is just fine. enabled=false does the job but it changes the color of the text too, I wanted it only to be not clickable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

From code you can use `MenuItem setEnabled(false)`, for [details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29). 
or, In your layout:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_item);
item.setVisible(true);
item.setEnabled(false);
```

or, In your menu.xml, add the following attribute in item

```
android:enabled="false"
```

below code to change the textColor
    // if you are using menu Item.
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
         // change the style here what you want

```
    return true;
}
```

As you are using Button the you can do the following.

```
button = (Button)R.id.buttonId;
  if(button.isenable)
  {
    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF")); //color code
   }
```

Comment: yeah, that's what I did.. but it puts the text in grey as if it is a disabled button.. I wanted a "look and feel" like a label, not a disabled button :) thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: you can change the get the id and logically set the text color to_your_preferred_color when item is disable.

Comment: good idea.. but how you do it? I've tried but without success, since seems that the text color of the items is immutable.

Comment: are you using button?

Comment: they are buttons as default, since they are items of a menu.. aren't they? Sorry but I'm maintaining something that I didn't write and the person who did is not available :)

Comment: with the first one there is no change at all, with the second one there is a nullpointer exception as gift :) since it's not a button :(